# Is it possible to identify speakers for each conversation after "autodetec" function in R

Tags: python, r, audio, split, speaker

I run the code below for wav file and I got 4 variables :sound.files, selec,       start, and end in output.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xc8V.png).  Does anyone know if it is possible to get speakers for each conversation so that we can know each star and end duration is speakerA talking or speakerB talking.

```
 autodetec(flist = sub, threshold = 0.5, env = "abs", ssmooth = 500, power = 1, redo = TRUE,
            bp=c(0,9), xl = 2, picsize = 2, res = 200, flim= c(0,10), osci = TRUE,
            wl = 300, ls = FALSE, sxrow = 2, rows = 4, mindur=0.5, maxdur=8, set = TRUE)
```

Comment: Where does this autodetect function come from?

Comment: from warbleR package

Answer (score 1):

The question builds on the theme of [speaker diarisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_diarisation). If you already have the homogeneous segments for each speaker (the outpue of your autodetect function), you could compute audio descriptors, such as the well-used [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum), to classify each segment. A simple classifier such as the [Kmeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), could do the work.